# How do i set parameters of rest api in InvokeHTTP of NiFi?

Tags: api, apache-nifi

I want to filter my rest api with date range. The rest api has dateFrom and dateTo parameters. I want to set dateFrom to 5 days ago and dateTo to now. How do i set the parameters in NiFi ?

My api looks like the below URL:

> https://api.aa/reports/api/order_report/?format=json&dateFrom=&dateTo=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your parameters in `HTTP URL` property, using the Nifi's Expression Language. E.g.:

```
https://api.aa/reports/api/order_report/?format=json&dateFrom=${now():toNumber():minus(86400000):multiply(5):format("yyyy-MM-dd")}&dateTo=${now():format("yyyy-MM-dd")}
```